# How to refer to 'once, twice, thrice' correctly in grammar terminology?

Tags: terminology

How to refer to '**once, twice, thrice**' correctly in grammar terminology?

I found sources which called them '**predeterminers**' ([see here](http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/determiners/determiners.htm)) and source that call them '**quantifiers**' ([see here](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=oHIqDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA37&lpg=PA37&dq=quantifiers%20once%20twice&source=bl&ots=2fUnvqTXjw&sig=0-8dDeF9u85ftKwkirxFetUH8Wo&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjv7_KQmqTbAhXEiiwKHZ9-CR8Q6AEIUTAE#v=onepage&q=quantifiers%20once%20twice&f=false)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say they are both. They are always quantifiers. Sometimes they are predeterminers and sometimes they are not.

Predeterminer:

> He charges twice the going rate.

Not a predeterminer:

> He asked me twice.

But they are still in the general linguistic class "quantifier."

Note what [this article](https://www.thoughtco.com/predeterminer-grammar-1691524) says about predeterminers:

> This set of quantifying elements is distinct from **ordinary quantifiers** . . .

In other words, they are still quantifiers, but they are distinct from quantifiers that can only be *postdeterminers* when used with a *central determiner*. For example, quantifiers like "many" and cardinal and ordinal numbers are always placed *after* a central determiner like "the":

> the many challenges
> the two red balloons
> the third time